SSL Handshake Error across several Fresh Oracle Linux 9 Installs
I have been trying to install the latest version of Oracle Linux 9.4, but I am unable use network functionality out-of-the-box or make any SSL connections, like updating packages or browsing the web. I installed in a Virtualbox VM the version with UEK kernel and the Nist 800-171 security policy selected. Other network tools like ping or dig work and resolve without issues.
EDIT: The problem is a bug specific to the NIST 800-171 security policy option, the error disappears in a fresh install with no policies selected.
This is the output of a package update immediately after fresh install -
[root@localhost]# yum upgrade -y
[sudo] password for root:
Oracle Linux 9 BaseOS Latest (x86_64)           0.0 B/s |    0  B    00:05
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'ol9_baseos_latest':
  - Curl error (35): SSL connect error for https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/baseos/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'ol9_baseos_latest': Cannot download repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

When I attempt to curl the URL I get the following -
[root@localhost]# curl -v https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/baseos/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
*    Trying 23.62.177.78:443...
* Connected to yum.oracle.com (23.62.177.78) port 443
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*    CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure

This is when I try to open Firefox, or any browser window -


"I installed in a Virtualbox VM" - what is the host OS? Note that in case of windows SSL interception done by some antivirus or other endpoint security might affect the traffic of the VM and then cause such effects you see.

The host is Windows 11 with all security software and firewalls disabled.

Does your internet connection go through any entity that might 'inspect' traffic like a business, government agency, school, etc? What does browser and/or curl give for a (rare) site that is still HTTP, like http://example.com ? Does openssl s_client -connect yum.oracle.com:443 </dev/null get an error or succeed? How about if you add -no_tls1_3?

This is due to the NIST 800-171 security policy selection during the installation of Oracle Linux 9.4 This policy imposes strict security settings, including restrictions on allowed TLS versions and ciphers, which are causing the SSL handshake errors.
Since you are in an installation stage, the cleanest would be:
Perform a fresh installation of Oracle Linux 9.4 and avoid selecting the NIST 800-171 security policy. This will prevent the restrictive settings from being applied.
If reinstalling is not an option, you can manually adjust the security settings after installation to relax the restrictions imposed by the NIST 800-171 policy. This involves editing the OpenSSL configuration or using update-crypto-policies tool to set a less restrictive policy.
Like this:
Modify the OpenSSL configuration file to allow more permissive settings.
vi /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

Adjust the settings under the [system_default_sect] section to include less restrictive protocols and ciphers.
Change the system-wide cryptographic policies.
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT

The DEFAULT policy is more permissive and should resolve the SSL handshake issues.
Test the connection to make sure the changes have taken effect.
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443

You can read helpful documentation about 800-171 and on this compliance document.
Good luck!
